# Is there a way to track CPU and memory usage of sub processes from another sub process

Tags: python, performance, process, celery, monitoring

I want to start a celery process that always runs in the background. I want these running process to be able to track system resource (CPU, RAM, etc) usage of all other processes that will be started when a new task is needed to be executed in parallel. And then I want the tracking process to log the data to file at a regular interval.

If the above implementation is possible, is it safe to use in production setup?

I haven't tried them, but I have read about psutil and py-spy. But I am not sure if they can be used to track processes from another parallel process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

psutil sure can.

```py
import psutil

p=psutil.Process(121000) # a pid you want to track. Father, son, brother, unrelated. It doesn't matter
p.cpu_percent()
# 1.4 my process use 1.4% of a cpu
p.cpu_times()
# pcputimes(user=42.4, system=0.01, children_user=0.0, children_system=0.0, iowait=0.01)
# Or detail
p.cpu_times().user, p.cpu_times().system
# Time spend so far, in sec

p.memory_percent()
#0.14 (0,14% memory used)
```

Answer (score 1):

> have read about psutil and py-spy. But I am not sure if they can be used to track processes from another parallel process.

Yes, they can.

They are similar to forking off a `$ ps axup ${PID}` child.
If ps can obtain a statistic, then so can psutil.

---

Using `wait4()` clearly only works for a child.

Using [`getrusage()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource.getrusage) works for self and for children.

Once upon a time ps needed sguid permission to read /dev/kmem.
The /proc pseudo filesystem tidied up some of the permission
details around that.